# Having trouble with semaphores in my project

Tags: c, unix, semaphore, shared-memory, critical-section

I have a project where I have 5 processes running, created with fork().  One parent and four children.  3 of the processes are bathers.  2 of the processes are boilerman.  The batherman and boilerman both enter the bathing area, wait a random amount of time and leave the bathing area and wait a random amount of time.  I have to use semaphores to make sure that 2 boilerman cannot enter the bathing area at the same time and a batherman and boilerman cannot enter the bathing area at the same time.

I am having trouble using the semaphores I am required to use to complete this project and any help telling me where I went wrong would be helpful.  I am using shared memory as well in this project.  I will include the two critical sections of the bather and boilerman and if you want me to add anymore code let me know.  Any help would be appreciated.

BATHERMAN CODE:

```
    create5();
   // The child process ----------------------------- //
   if (process_id == 0 && p_shm->programCounter < 3)
   {
       p_shm->programCounter++;
        printf( "[BA] pid %d from pid %d\n", getpid(), getppid() );

        //CRITICAL SECTION
        if(process_id == 0 && p_shm->ba_num == 0){
            my_TID = 1;
            p_shm->ba_num++;
        }else if(process_id == 0 && p_shm->ba_num == 1){
            my_TID = 2;
            p_shm->ba_num++;
        }else if(process_id == 0 && p_shm->ba_num == 2){
            my_TID = 3;
            p_shm->ba_num++;
        }

         while (p_shm->boiler_done_flag == 0)
       {
              // WAIT on the semaphore M2

            operations[0].sem_num = 1;
            operations[0].sem_op = -1; // "wait" on the semaphore   
            operations[0].sem_flg = 0;  
            ret_val = semop(sem_id, operations, 1);         
            if (ret_val != 0)  
            {   
                fprintf(stderr, "P-OP(wait) failed (child) ....\a\n");   
            }  

                     sleep_time = RAND(BATHER_TIME_01);
                     usleep(sleep_time);

           p_shm->bather_count++;
           if(p_shm->bather_count == 1){

               // WAIT on the semaphore M1
            operations[0].sem_num = 0;
            operations[0].sem_op = -1; // "wait" on the semaphore   
            operations[0].sem_flg = 0;  
            ret_val = semop(sem_id, operations, 1);         
            if (ret_val != 0)  
            {   
                fprintf(stderr, "P-OP(wait) failed (child) ....\a\n");   
            }

           }

              // SIGNAL on the semaphore M2
            operations[0].sem_num = 1;  
            operations[0].sem_op  = 1;  
            operations[0].sem_flg = 0;  
            ret_val = semop(sem_id, operations, 1);   
            if (ret_val != 0)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "V-OP (wait) failed (child) ....\a\n");    
            }  

                     // the critical section starts here -------------------
                     printf("T%d is entering the bathing area ..\n", my_TID);

                         // do nothing .. it’s time to relax!!
                     sleep_time = BATHER_TIME_02;
                     usleep(sleep_time); 
                     printf ("T%d is leaving the bathing area ..\n", my_TID);
                     // the critical section ends here --------------------

            // WAIT on the semaphore M2
            operations[0].sem_num = 1;
            operations[0].sem_op = -1; // "wait" on the semaphore   
            operations[0].sem_flg = 0;  
            ret_val = semop(sem_id, operations, 1);         
            if (ret_val != 0)  
            {   
                fprintf(stderr, "P-OP(wait) failed (child) ....\a\n");   
            }

            p_shm->bather_count--;
            if(p_shm->bather_count == 0){

                // SIGNAL on the semaphore M2
            operations[0].sem_num = 1;  
            operations[0].sem_op  = 1;  
            operations[0].sem_flg = 0;  
            ret_val = semop(sem_id, operations, 1);   
            if (ret_val != 0)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "V-OP (wait) failed (child) ....\a\n");    
            }  

            }

            // SIGNAL on the semaphore M1
            operations[0].sem_num = ;  
            operations[0].sem_op  = 1;  
            operations[0].sem_flg = 0;  
            ret_val = semop(sem_id, operations, 1);   
            if (ret_val != 0)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "V-OP (wait) failed (child) ....\a\n");    
            }  
      }

        //CRITICAL SECTION END



       exit(0);
   }
```

BOILERMAN CODE:

```
// The parent process ----------------------------- //   
   else if(process_id > 0 || p_shm->programCounter == 3)
   {     
         printf( "[BO] pid %d\n", getpid() ); 


         //CRITICAL SECTION

         for (i = 0; i < NUM_REPEAT; i ++)
       {
           if(process_id > 0){
               my_BID = 2;
           }else{
               my_BID = 1;
           }


                     sleep_time = RAND(BOLIERMAN_TIME_01);
                     usleep(sleep_time);
            // WAIT on the semaphore M1
            operations[0].sem_num = 0;
            operations[0].sem_op = -1; // "wait" on the semaphore   
            operations[0].sem_flg = 0;  
            ret_val = semop(sem_id, operations, 1);         
            if (ret_val != 0)  
            {   
                fprintf(stderr, "P-OP(wait) failed (child) ....\a\n");   
            }
                     // the critical section starts here -------------------
                     printf ("B%d starts his boiler …..\n", my_BID);
                         //  I am working hard now … 
                     sleep_time = BOLIERMAN_TIME_02;
                     usleep(sleep_time);
                     printf ("B%d is leaving the bathing area ..\n", my_BID);
                     // the critical section ends here --------------------
            // SIGNAL on the semaphore M1
            operations[0].sem_num = 0;  
            operations[0].sem_op  = 1;  
            operations[0].sem_flg = 0;  
            ret_val = semop(sem_id, operations, 1);   
            if (ret_val != 0)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "V-OP (wait) failed (child) ....\a\n");    
            }  
      }

      p_shm->boiler_done_flag = 1;

         //CRITICAL SECTION END


        if(process_id == 0){
            exit(0);
        }
        // detach the shared memory ---
        ret_val = shmdt(p_shm);  
        if (ret_val != 0) 
        {  printf ("shared memory detach failed ....\n"); }

        ret_val = shmctl(shm_id, IPC_RMID, 0); 
        if (ret_val != 0)
        {  printf("shared memory ID remove ID failed ... \n"); } 

        ret_val = semctl(sem_id, IPC_RMID, 0);  
        if (ret_val != 0)
        {  printf("semaphore remove ID failed ... \n"); }

        exit(0);  
   }
```

Comment: "I am having trouble" does not tell us what specific problems you are having nor does it describe the current behaviour of your program. You cannot expect us to debug the whole thing for you so describing the behaviour of your program, what you have found in your debugging and asking a specific question are all  important. Review [ask].

Comment: Please read through all of [ask] and [mcve].